# Local Image Not Displaying in Crystal Report ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I have created an MVC application that has an aspx page as report view that will render the Crystal report.

I have added a simple Picture and OLE object and set the "Format Object -> Picture -> Graphic Location" as my local physical path. I'm expecting the image to be rendered from the path specified at my Crystal report but the image is not displaying at all. Its throwing error in browser console as

```
 "xxx/Webform/CrystalImageHandler.aspx?dynamicimage=cr_tmp_image_225a5398-7162-4373-b860-ce62f2c67c24.png"
```

Based on my reseach I found suggestions to add 2 different handlers for "path=CrystalImageHandler.aspx" in Web.Config file, but it doesn't seems to be work for me.

Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: Is your image added to the website? Did you publish your site to IIS? Can you talk us a litle bit more of your environment? Regards.

Comment: If I remember correctly, I tried to load from my local path. I didn't try host it in IIS.

Comment: What is the browse error you are having?

Answer (score 0):

Initially when I start implementing, I thought of adding the image dynamically from data source but due to this issue I just added an image field via OLE object and suppressed​ it conditionally.  Again, it's not a solution to my problem it's just a fix.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of emmbedding the image , try providing url either in the formula or parameter from the code behind.